# Passing ViewBag (has list of int type) to Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to pass list of int type to Controller on jquery  load, but not successfull.
Here is my code:

```
function Addcov() {
    var dt = '@ViewBag.dt';
    @{
        List<int> covtypes = new List<int>();
        foreach (var item in ViewBag.CovTypes)
        {
            covtypes.Add(item);
        }
    }
    alert('@covtypes');

    $("#Form").dialog({
         autoOpen: true,
         width: 1000,
         resizable: false,
         title: 'Add',
         modal: true,
         open: function () {
             $(this).load(
                 '../controller/AddAction', 
                 { fromDate: dt, CovTypes: JSON.stringify('@covtypes') },
                 function (response, status, xhr) {});
             },
             buttons: {}
        });
    }
```

Comment: Whats the problem then?

Comment: You are confusing Razor code (server-side) with javascript (client-side). The two don't interact directly. You use Razor to generate javascript -- view source of the rendered page to see the code that will run. Here's how to [pass the list to javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15291609/2030565).

Answer (score 0):

I might see your problem, the path. debug and make sure that the path you are passing is correct and that the data actually being passed through the covtypes.

The main issue that I see here, is the path, which is not passed correctly. 
Try with the full path and see what happens.

Comment: The path is correct and data posted to 'fromDate' is valid but, 'covtypes' posted as   -- System.[List.Int32 ...But not the actual list

Comment: Of Course! because your list is List<int> covtypes = new List<int>(); the list has no data inside it has an int! so the list contains data of System.[List.Int32]. you need to pass your value instead of an int. edit: note that you also stringify the '@covtypes' so the json sees the list, but doesn't look in the foreach value. So you get in return : System.[List.Int32]

Answer (score 0):

it would be helpful if you've written the calling method on your controller, but in your case you're sending a `Get` request , therefore, you might indicate that this values are coming from URI, like follows:

```
public ActionResult AddAction(object fromDate, [FromUri] List<int> arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

i can suggest put values of ViewBag [List of int] as csv in html element and later convert them to array of int and pass to controller as

```
<input type="hidden" id="list" value="@ViewBag.CovTypes.Aggregate((x,y)=>x+","+y)" />

function Addcov() {
 var data=$("#list").val().split(",")map(function(i,e){   return parseInt(e);          });

$("#Form").dialog({
     autoOpen: true,
     width: 1000,
     resizable: false,
     title: 'Add',
     modal: true,
     open: function () {
         $(this).load(
             '../controller/AddAction', 
             { fromDate: dt, CovTypes:JSON.stringify(data) },
             function (response, status, xhr) {});
         },
         buttons: {}
    });
 }
```