# Using a C# list in a javascript snippet

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays, serialization

I want to use two arrays from `C#` in the `JS` snippet in a view. In order to do so I've tried to use the `JavaScriptSerializer()` but the data array isn't getting any values (the view's source shows it as follows):

```
 var mydata =
```

Every example I've come across injects the C# code in JS by using `<%=%>` tags. This doesn't yield any results for me since I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4. Therefore I tried it with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var mydata = @{ new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.GetData());}

 $(function () {
  // Generates a chart using the mydata array
 }
</script>
```

What's wrong about this syntax? When I try to add an array for the headers underneath it, I receive a compilation error. There are warnings that the lines aren't terminated, but when I add `;` at the end of each line it gives a syntax error as well (no specific error, just 'syntax error').

The data in `GetData()` and `GetHeaders()` are defined as such:

```
public List<int> GetData() {
    return new List<int>(new[] { 4, 5, 6});
}
```

I've tried returning it as a `int[]` but this made no difference.
How can I use a C# list/array in a JavaScript snippet?

Edit: image of the unknown compilation error.
When I don't place the semicolons I get a syntax error on the second `var`. I get a suggestion to terminate the line endings, which adds the semicolons to the end. Then I have the issue as shown below. Curious detail: there are no red bars to the side of the file that usually indicate where the error is located.

That being said: when executing the script, the arrays have their expected values and everything works as it should.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `@{ }` creates a block of code, it doesn't print the result to the rendered page. You can do this:

```
@{ 
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    @serializer.Serialize(Model.GetData())
}
```

Or even better, use the [`Json`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json_methods%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) helper:

```
@Json.Encode(Model.GetData())
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! One issue remains however: I get a warning saying the statement isn't terminated. When I add a semicolon at the end I receive a compilation error. What causes this? (I'm talking about `var mydata = @{ @Json.Encode(Model.GetData()) };`)

Comment: @JeroenVannevel That's the same problem you had with your original code. A `@{ }` code block won't render a value when used like that. Just use var `mydata = @Json.Encode(Model.GetData())` instead.

Comment: Ofcourse, silly mistake. I do keep getting the syntax errors though, I have edited my post to clarify what I'm talking about.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I think your code is fine now. It's just visual studio complaining because it's confused about what that semicolon means. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111729/razor-javascript-and-trailing-semicolon

Comment: Aha, thanks a lot! That clarified a lot of confusion. Everything is working splendidly now, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

When you enclose operations within code blocks the output won't be rendered unless you explicitly tells it to render.

Try this one:

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.GetData()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the result of the serializer in single quotes, like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = '@{ new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.GetData());}';
</script>
```

You can create a HTML helper to call this, example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = '@Html.JSSerializerHelper(Model.GetData())';
</script>
```

Only one way that I think most elegant.

Answer (score -1):

You could convert your List into JavaScript array to use within js.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mydata = [];
    @foreach(int i in Model.GetData()) {
         <text>mydata.push(@i);</text>
    }

    $(function () {
       // Generates a chart using the mydata array
    }
</script>
```