# Writing Javascript with Razor and Resharper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, resharper

I am trying to write the following javascript in Razor (MVC4).

(The Script tags are there)

```
 var isPaid = true;
```

in the view I use the Model to get the value:

```
 var isPaid = @Model.Paid;

 <text>
    var proceed = @Model.Paid;
 </text> 

 var proceed = @Html.Raw(Model.Paid + ";")
```

Most of the time Resharper complains

Comment: What does resharper complain about? Maybe it is because you have HTML within your javascript code.

Comment: @OP - In your view, wrap it in <script> tags.  To get the value at runtime, try `<script type="text/javascript">var proceed = @Model.Paid;
</script>`.  However, can you explain a bit more?  Are you trying to write the entire line `var isPaid = true;` or are you trying to set the value of `var isPaid` at runtime?  Also you stated "using the model/ I've tried:", did you mean View?

Comment: possible duplicate of [razor/javascript and trailing semicolon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111729/razor-javascript-and-trailing-semicolon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isPaid = false; // This is JavaScript.

    // The if statement is C#, hence the @.
    @if (Model.Paid)
    {
        @:isPaid = true;  // Set the JS variable to true.
    }

    // Below is JavaScript code again.
    alert(isPaid);
</script>
```

Text after the `@:` nugget will be interpreted as as JavaScript. It is a bit of a hassle for booleans, a `string` property for example is a lot easier:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var userName = '@Model.UserName';
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't combine JavaScript inside HTML code and you need to put quotes & angle-brackets around the value so that it is considered as a string.

**The problem seems to be this and more..:**

```
var isPaid = @Model.Paid;

 <text>
    var proceed = @Model.Paid;
 </text>
```

**A proposed solution would be:**

Normal JavaScript code should resides within a `script` tag, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var isPaid = '<%: @Model.Paid %>';
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is with Razor (MVC 4) not asp.net web pages.