# Ajax call Parameter does not accept @Model as parameter value

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have following code which is making an Ajax call from a `.CSHTML` file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#Save").click(function () {
        var model = {
            EmployeeId: @Model.EmployeeId,
            OverrideTermDate: $('#OverrideTermDate').val(),
            OverrideHireDate: $('#OverrideHireDate').val(),
        };
        $.ajax({
            data: @Model.EmployeeId,
            url: "/Employee/UpdateOverrideDates",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (result) {
                $(function () {
                    $("#dialog").dialog();
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

My VS shows syntax error. But instead of `@Model.EmployeeId` if I hardcode it to any int value like 1 then it works fine.

Now  `@Model.EmployeeId`  is not NULL and it is an int. It is just that Ajax does not like it. Any idea why? Should I not be using @Razor components in Ajax calls?

Comment: You shouldn't use Razor components in JS instead you can make a hidden field in Razor and use it in your jQuery code

Comment: Try using `data: '@Model.EmployeeId'` but this script needs to be in your view and not JS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Razor in JS, wrap the attributes in `''`,

```
data : '@Model.EmployeeId',  

//For passing integer use parseInt('@Model.EmployeeId') or Number('@Model.EmployeeId')
```

and

```
var model = {
        EmployeeId: '@Model.EmployeeId',
        ....
};
```

The quotes act as delimiters, so the Razor parser recognizes the values.

or Alternatively,

```
data : @Model.EmployeeId + "",
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just a bug in Visual Studio, the view should works as excepted.
The answer was explained here: [Razor/JavaScript and trailing semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111729/razor-javascript-and-trailing-semicolon).

If you don't like it, you can just put the "plus zero" after the @Model

```
$("#Save").click(function () {
    var model = {
        EmployeeId: @Model.EmployeeId + 0,
        OverrideTermDate: $('#OverrideTermDate').val(),
        OverrideHireDate: $('#OverrideHireDate').val(),
    };
    $.ajax({
        data: @Model.EmployeeId + 0,
        url: "/Employee/UpdateOverrideDates",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (result) {
            $(function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog();
            });
        }
    });
});
```