# How to fix syntax error in Site.cshtml

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, vs-community-edition

ASP.NET 4.6 MVC 4 application site.cshtml contains javascript global variables defined in head element as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    "use strict";
    var BASE_URL = '@Url.Content("~/")',
        Message = {
            selectRows: @IR("Vali read"),
            sendingQuery: @IR("Päringu saatmine"),
            palunValiRead: @IR("Märgi arved, mida tasutakse"),
            saved: @IR("Salvestatud")
            };
</script>
```

In Visual Studio 2015 razor editor last line

```
            };
```

is marked as syntax error:

[image: synterror]

How to fix this so that it appears without error mark ?

Comment: What is `IR`? And does it still run OK?

Comment: IR is function in viewmodel base class which returns MvcHtmlString type javascript string which contains message text in user language. It works OK and allows javascript to output messages in user language. IR returns proper javascript string in `'` quotes. This makes view easier to read. view is not polluted with quotes, @Html.Raw and javascript serializer calls.

Comment: Have you tried removing the semicolon charcter `;`?

Comment: After removing `;` VS still shows syntax error

Comment: Its just an issue with VS (refer the answers to [Razor/JavaScript and trailing semicolon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111729/razor-javascript-and-trailing))

Comment: @StephenMuecke I read answers in referenced question. I tried to add parentheses in two ways: `(@IR("Salvestatud"))` and `@(IR("Salvestatud"))` . Tried to remove semicolon. Error still appears. Using `@: saved: @IR("Salvestatud")` causes error to move to `@` character without popup message. What is simplest way to remove this error in my case using minimum number of addtional characters in view to keep view clean ?

Comment: Have you tried quoting them - `selectRows: '@IR("Vali read")', sendingQuery: '@IR("Päringu saatmine")',` etc

Comment: Quoting works. However this produces invalid javascript since IR() returns quoted string. Every string needs translared so there are huge number of `IR()` calls in code. Refactoring `IR()` to return data without quotes and wrapping every IR call into quotes makes view ugly. `@IR("Salvestatud")+''` also works. So probably `+''` should added to last string in those cases to make error disappear